# Perl for loop assignment by reference

Tags: perl

So I am wondering if there is a better way of doing the following:

I have an array of lines that I want to print out multiple times and replace certain things differently each time.  For example:

```
my @array = ("I like most animals.\n", "Most animals like me.\n");
my @animals = ("dogs", "cats");
foreach my $animal (@animals) {
    foreach my $sentence (@array) {
        $sentence =~ s/animals/$animal/g;
        print $sentence;
    }
}
```

The problem with this being this only works the first time because animals get replaced in the original array.  To get around this inside my for loop I just do something like `my $line = $sentence;` and then just regex and print $line instead.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `r` flag in newer perls can help (5.14 onwards)

The problem is - if you do a "sed style" pattern replace on `$sentence` it's an alias to the array element, not a variable in it's own right.

That's because of how array iterators work - it allows you to modify an element in a loop, and have it update the original:

```
foreach my $value ( @list_of_things ) { 
    $value++;
}
```

Will alter `@list_of_things`. And this is effectively what your pattern replacement is doing. We need to copy it before we do that, so we can preserve the original - or use the `r` flag - to avoid that happening.

So the easiest way is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = ("I like most animals.\n", "Most animals like me.\n");
my @animals = ("dogs", "cats");
foreach my $animal (@animals) {
    foreach my $sentence (@array) {
        print $sentence=~ s/animals/$animal/r;
    }
}
```

You can probably lose the `g` as well, as it appears to be redundant.

Output:

```
I like most dogs.
Most dogs like me.
I like most cats.
Most cats like me.
```

But you don't actually need `$sentence` any more at all:

```
foreach my $animal (@animals) {
    for (@array) {
        print s/animals/$animal/r;
    }
}
```

In older perls, as [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) notes - you can do the same by copying the alias to a local variable:

```
(my $s = $sentence) =~ s/animals/$animal/g;
print $s;
```

Comment: In older Perls, you need to use `(my $s = $sentence) =~ s/animals/$animal/g; print $s;`.

Comment: Perl 5.10 is 6 years old now. That's ancient in software terms. Updating it might help, but failing that - see @choroba's comment (and my edit to the question)

Comment: @Sobrique Can't upgrade as it is a supported system, so I'm learning the version that is supported. Also can you explain the `if you do a "sed style" pattern replace on $sentence it's an alias to the array element, not a 'thing' in it's own right.` a bit more please or provide a link if possible.

Comment: There's some about it in [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements) but it's a bit dry

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a template. Here is an example using [Template](http://p3rl.org/Template):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Template;

my @array = ( "I like most [% animals %].\n",
              "Most [% animals %] like me.\n",
            );
my @animals = qw( dogs cats );

my $template = 'Template'->new;

for my $animal (@animals) {
    for my $sentence (@array) {
        $template->process(\$sentence, { animals => $animal });
    }
}
```

Comment: What version do you need for Template ?

Comment: @123: It [seems to work](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Template-Toolkit+2.26) OK on 5.8.3 and higher.

Comment: Oh, doesn't seem to work on mine, mustn't have built with the module :(

Comment: `IT department reluctance`, yep, so not allowed :)